# Why am I getting Failed prop type using react router and nested components

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-proptypes

So, I have a site with react router, and redux (example below is severely simplified)

```
<Route path="/" component={ A } >
  <Route path="/B" component={B} />
</Route>
```

**A.jsx**

```
class A extends Component {
    render () {
        const calculated_value_to_pass_down = FooBar()
        return (
            <div>
                {React.Children.map(this.props.children,
                    (child) => React.cloneElement(child, {
                        required_prop: calculated_value_to_pass_down
                    })
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
}    
export default A
```

**B.jsx**

```
class B extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                { this.props.required_prop }
            </div>
        )
    }
}    
B.propTypes = {
    required_prop: PropTypes.any.isRequired
}    
export default B
```

But, when I go to `localhost:8080/B` I get a error backtrace:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `required_prop` is marked as required in `B`, but its value is `undefined`.
in A (created by RouterContext)
in RouterContext (created by Router)
in Router
in Provider
```

The page 100% works. And the error doesn't happen in production, but I hate the error showing up at all.

The page never actually renders with the undefined props even, I get the error before render is even called.

I know I could simply remove the .isRequired and it will work, but that idea smells rotten.

thanks!

Comment: where you are passing the props to component B ?

Comment: Is `calculated_value_to_pass_down` undefined? @MayankShukla inside `React.cloneElement` i believe

Comment: when I do `console.log(this.props.required_prop)` on B.jsx's render method I always get a value, never `undefined`

Comment: @MayankShukla I am passing the props via the cloneElement map in A.jsx

Comment: There is a big discussion already here : https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1857#issuecomment-180879045

Comment: Looks like it's intentional: "This is intentional; validating props at element creation time produces more useful errors. It also more closely matches the behavior of static type systems like Flow. Best for now is to simply mark those props optional. We also may introduce a feature in the future called context that will give another supported way to pass props from a parent..." -> https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4494

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried many ways, but didn't get the reason of this warning. One thing i can guess but not sure, `cloneElement` as per [DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement):

> Clone and return a new React element using element as the starting
>   point. The resulting element will have the original element's props
>   with the new props merged in shallowly. New children will replace
>   existing children.

`cloneElement` copy the existing element, may be that component first get created without props then get copied.

**Temporary solution** is, you can use `defaultProps` to define the default value of that `prop`, by doing this it will not throw the warning, Like this:

```
B.defaultProps = {
    required_prop: ''
}
```

Comment: Ahh, your comments led me down the correct path re: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1857#issuecomment-180879045 and it seems that there is no perfect way to do what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear in production because those warnings are not shown/used in production, but still the error is there. (propTypes are removed from production code)

Your problem is that the A.jsx is rendering B.jsx even before FooBar() is finished, meaning it sends calculated_value_to_pass_down whose value is initially undefined, and if your B.jsx component doesn't want to have empty props then the solution would be to check in A.jsx if calculated_value_to_pass_down is not undefined, if it is undefined don't render B.jsx component.

```
<div>
   {calculated_value_to_pass_down!==undefined? React.Children.map(this.props.children,
     (child) => React.cloneElement(child, {
        required_prop: calculated_value_to_pass_down
        })
     ) : <div>LOADING</div>}
</div>
```

Comment: one doubt, he is calling that `function` before `return`, so how `A` is rendering `B` before `FooBar()` ??

Comment: DOM doesn't wait on calculations to finish to be rendered, once the calculation is done it will only update appropriately, but it will never wait for it

Comment: i think, that is not the issue, i just run that code locally with `const calculated_value_to_pass_down = 'abc'`, still getting the same error :)

Comment: Yeah, I knew why it didn't show it production, that was more of a 'i could ignore because, but don't want to' comment. :)

Comment: `console.log(this.props.required_prop)` on B.jsx's `render` method never show up undefined. It seems to be a problem with using `React.cloneElement` to pass the props to the children.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @malayank-shukla's answer I realized the issue is in the `React.cloneElement` part of the code.

There is more discussion at : [ReactTraining's Github Issues](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1857#issuecomment-180879045)

It seems the solutions are:

1. Remove `.isRequired` from PropTypes
2. Set defaults from PropTypes
3. Wrap child component in wrapper component that sets the props with defaults until proper props are sent in (in case you use B.jsx multiple places and don't want to remove PropType usage everywhere
4. There is an option for React-Router v4 that allows you to write a render attribute instead of a component attribute on the route; but it doesn't work for my case; or I don't understand it properly?

   ```js
   <Route
       exact
       path="/b"
       render={routeProps => <B {...props} {...routeProps} />}
   />
   ```

I look forward to any other answers